# How to define common property for two different entities in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities Student and course as below

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeacherId))]
    public  int TeacherId {get;set;}
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add list of grades to two entities containing grade and id of the course or Student depending on the situation. Do I have to define a entity grade with studentId and CourseId or is there any other way to do it without creating entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a m:n-relationship between `Course` and `Student` with the extra information of the grade that was awarded for the participation. By creating the two navigation properties `Student.Courses` and `Course.Students` you have already created an implicit crosstab between the entities. In order to add the grade, I'd propose to create a dedicated entity, e.g. `CourseParticipation` that defines the relationship between `Course` and `Student` and also carries the extra information (up to now, the grade, later maybe more):

```
public class CourseParticipation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<CourseParticipation> Courses { get; set; }
}
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<CourseParticipation> Participants { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TeacherId))]
    public  int TeacherId {get;set;}
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

This way, you make the relationship explicit and are prepared for later additions to the relationship.